# JQuery JTable - Difference between data.row and data.record

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

I have started working on jTable, a jQuery plugin to create grids. I was going through the documentation. There I came across 2 terms - data.record and data.row. I have always understood that rows and records are synonymous. But obviously, in JTable, they mean different things and am not sure about the difference. It will be great if anybody can shed some light on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.jtable.org/ApiReference/Events) you can find where to use `data.row` and `data.record`

`data.row` returns table row (`tr`) where we can get `tr` properties like innerHTML, innerText, className, cells etc.

and

`data.record` returns object where we can get data using columns names.
for example- `data.record.FirstName`
 which will return one value of specific column.

Hope this is clear to you. In case of query revert back.

Comment: Yep. I had gone through the documentation even before I asked the question. But was confused regarding the difference between the two. But your explanation was simple and good. I get it now. Thanks.